# Download multiple PDFs at once

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, download

I am trying to download multiple documents at once from each webpage. On each webpage, there are multiple links. each link opens a new tab where there's another link to click which opens another tab to the PDF doc where I can download it. I need to download all the PDFs but it's going to take so long to do it one at a time. I've tried the Batch Link chrome extension, but it just downloads the webpage of the link to get to the PDF. Is there any way to download these PDFs at once from the initial webpage without having to click twice to open the doc and download it? I am using Google Chrome on Mac.

Comment: i believe in chrome there is a shortcut. Try clicking the pdf link while pressing ALT. See if that works. (What it does is download the file instead of opening it)

Comment: Can you tell us the website?